# Receiving information from social media into iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

As the title suggests I want to add Social media extensions into my iOS application, I have seen multiple tutorials on how to publish to an external source e.g. Facebook, Twitter, Instagram etc... which seems easy enough.

Now my question is it possible to do the reverse and instead retrieve information from these external factors? For example if I set the application to look directly at my Facebook profile when loaded and retrieve my Facebook status's.

I've heard of the concept of a Facebook Graph API which I plan on learning of the next couple of weeks. I'm looking for any resource materials or videos which I can use to learn from. I'm currently looking through Facebook's developers options but any additional information would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to want to use their official API. These links are a good starting point.

[Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios)

[Twitter SDK for iOS](https://dev.twitter.com/mopub/ios)

[Instagram support for iOS](https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/iphone-hooks/)

Comment: Thanks, we all got to start some where.